# Multilevel Unordered List from a Query's Result Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multi-level

I made a query which i can populate a table with following theads using all rows of that query.

```
section_id | section | category_id | category | subcategory_id | subcategory
```

Now I am trying to create a multilevel unordered list from this populated table. Is it possible to do it? Result should like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Section Name
    <ul>
      <li>Category name for above section
        <ul>
          <li>Subcategory name for above category and section</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps (untested):

```
$tree = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tree[$row['section_id']]['name'] = $row['section'];
    $tree[$row['section_id']]['categories'][$row['category_id']]['name'] = $row['category'];
    $tree[$row['section_id']]['categories'][$row['category_id']]['subcategories'][$row['subcategory_id']]['name'] = $row['subcategory'];
}

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($tree as $sec_id => $section) {
    printf('<li><a href="test.php?sec=%d">%s</a><ul>', $sec_id, $section['name']);
    foreach ($section['categories'] as $cat_id => $category) {
        printf('<li><a href="test.php?sec=%d&cat=%d">%s</a><ul>', $sec_id, $cat_id, $category['name']);
        foreach ($category['subcategories'] as $scat_id => $subcategory) {
            printf('<li><a href="test.php?sec=%d&cat=%d&scat=%d">%s</a></li>', $sec_id, $cat_id, $scat_id, $subcategory['name']);
        }
        echo '</ul></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: One more question.. how can we assign links in this tree?
 For example, `echo '<li>' . $section['name'] . '<ul>';` should link to `test.php?sec='$section_id'`. Main format is `?sec=$section_id&cat=category_id&scat=$subcategory_id` . Thank you.

Comment: @yahya. Oh, c'mon. That's really basic PHP. See my updated answer, but that should have taken you just 5 minutes to figure out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to see if any easier way than mine:
`/* Add ids to array */
$tree[$row['section_id']]['id'] = $row['section_id'];
$tree[$row['section_id']]['categories'][$row['category_id']]['id'] = $row['category_id'];
$tree[$row['section_id']]['categories'][$row['category_id']]['subcategories'][$row['subcategory_id']]['id'] = $row['subcategory_id'];`
Links:
`foreach ($category['subcategories'] as $subcategory) {
echo '<li><a href="content.php?sec=' . $section['id'] . '&cat=' . $category['id'] . '&scat=' . $subcategory['id'] . '&getDetail=">' . $subcategory['name'] . '</a></li>';` Thanksx2

Comment: Basically the same. Just different syntactic sugar.

Comment: Yours is much clean and time-saver. Solved %100. Thanks again and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Back to topic, this code is only working for if you have set all three of section, category and subcategory. If you are planning to use this as navigation menu and have some part which has only i.e. section level, or section&category level, this query will not show them. My basic solution can be found in the following link which is also asked for how to beautify it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828960/building-unordered-list-navigation-menu-with-an-easier-way-code-beautifying-que)[link]