# Building unordered list navigation menu with an easier way - Code Beautifying Question

Tags: php, dynamic, menu, navigation

I wrote a dynamic menu based on three table on db which reflects below level frame:

```
> Section
>> Categories
>>> Subcategory
```

Here is my code:

```
include("connDB.php");

echo '<ul>';
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM section ORDER BY section_name ASC");

while($getSection = mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {
    echo "<li><a href='content.php?sec={$getSection['section_id']}&cat='>{$getSection['section_name']}</a>";

    $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE section_id = '{$getSection['section_id']}'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($q2) > 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($getCat = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
            echo "<li><a href='content.php?sec={$getSection['section_id']}&cat={$getCat['category_id']}&scat='>{$getCat['category_name']}</a>";

            $q3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE category_id = '{$getCat['category_id']}'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($q3) > 0) {
                echo "<ul>";
                while($getSubCat = mysql_fetch_array($q3)) {
                    echo "<li><a href='content.php?sec={$getSection['section_id']}&cat={$getCat['category_id']}&scat={$getSubCat['subcategory_id']}&getDetail='>{$getSubCat['subcategory_name']}</a></li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

I am wondering if I can find any help to beautify this basic-level code to a better way, more professional way?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

remodel your three tables to just one, then change the recurisve calling to one sql statement, and do a little php-looping to create the list. :)

Comment: I thinks it is also best way but not applicable to my current project. Anyway thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is an old question. However, for anyone who stumbles upon this there is a solution. It's identical to the other answer however it's also sometimes referred to as [Modified Preordered Tree Traversal (MPTT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Some web frameworks, like [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) and Django, have it built in and refer to it as a "Tree" it would greatly increase the flexibility of your menu as well as preserve order.